# Python 3 - calculate total in if else function using for loop

Tags: python-3.x

If anybody can give me some hints to point me in the right direction so I can solve it myself that would be great.
I am trying to calculate the total and average income depending on number of employee's. Do I have to make another list or iterate the current list (list1) to solve.

```
def get_input():

    Name = input("Enter a name: ")
    Hours = float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
    Rate = float(input("Enter hourly rate: "))

    return Name, Hours, Rate

def calc_pay(Hours, Rate):

    if Hours > 40:
        overtime = (40 * Rate) + (Hours - 40) * (Rate * 1.5)
        print(list1[0], "should be paid", overtime)
    else:
        no_overtime = (Hours * Rate)
        print(list1[0], "should be paid", no_overtime)

    return Hours, Rate



x = int(input("Enter the number of employees: "))

for i in range(x):
   list1 = list(get_input())
   calc_pay(list1[1], list1[2])

   i += 1
```

Comment: You almost got it OP. All you need to do is call the `get_input()` function and store the returned values. Then, you need to pass those values to `calc_pay()` function

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of the total pay for all the employees, you probably need to make two major changes to your code.

The first is to change `calc_pay` to `return` the calculated pay amount instead of only printing it (the current return value is pretty useless, since the caller already has those values). You may want to skip printing in the function (since calculating the value and returning it is the function's main job) and let that get done by the caller, if necessary.

The second change is to add the pay values together in your top level code. You could either append the pay values to a list and add them up at the end (with `sum`), or you could just keep track of a running total and add each employee's pay to it after you compute it.

There are a few other minor things I'd probably change in your code if I was writing it, but they're not problems with its correctness, just style issues.

The first is variable names. Python has a guide, [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) that makes a bunch of suggestions about coding style. It's only an official rule for the Python code that's part of the standard library, but many other Python programmers use it loosely as a baseline style for all Python projects. It recommends using `lowercase_names_with_underscores` for most variable and function names, and reserving `CapitalizedNames` for classes. So I'd use `name`, `hours` and `rate` instead of the capitalized versions of those names. I'd also strongly recommend that you use meaningful names instead of generic names like `x`. Some short names like `i` and `x` can be useful in some situations (like coordinates and indexes), but I'd avoid using them for any non-generic purpose. You also don't seem to be using your `i` variable for anything useful, so it might make sense to rename it `_`, which suggests that it's not going to be used. I'd use `num_employees` or something similar instead of `x`. The name `list1` is also bad, but I suggest doing away with that list entirely below. Variable names with numbers in them are often a bad idea. If you're using a lot of numbered names together (e.g. `list1`, `list2`, `list3`, etc.), you probably should be putting your values in a single list instead (a list of lists) instead of the numbered variables. If you just have a few, they should just have more specific names (e.g. `employee_data` instead of `list1`).

My second suggestion is about handling the return value from `get_input`. You can unpack the tuple of values returned by the function into separate variables, rather than putting them into a list. Just put the names separated by commas on the left side of the `=` operator:

```
name, hours, rate = get_input()
calc_pay(hours, rate)
```

My last minor suggestion is about avoiding repetition in your code. A well known programming suggestion is "Don't Repeat Yourself" (often abbreviated DRY), since repeated (especially copy/pasted) code is hard to modify later and sometimes harbors subtle bugs. Your `calc_pay` function has a repeated `print` line that could easily be moved outside of the `if`/`else` block so that it doesn't need to be repeated. Just have both branches of the conditional code write the computed pay to the same variable name (instead of different names) and then use that single variable in the print line (and a `return` line if you follow my suggested fix above for the main issue of your question).

Comment: I got the first change but I don't understand how exactly do you do the second change?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help people. Here was the answer

```
payList = []

num_of_emps = int(input("Enter number of employees: "))

for i in range(num_of_emps):           

name, hours, rate = get_input()   

pay = calc_pay(hours, rate) 

payList.append(pay)

total = sum(payList)

avg = total / num_of_emps
print("The total amount to be paid is $", format(total, ",.2f"), sep="")
print("\nThe average employee is paid $", format(avg, ",.2f"), sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter objects mass, then calculate its weight.
 If the object weighs more than 500.
Else the object weighs less than 100.

Use formula:  weight = mass x 9.8